# Android Custom EditText with a Left Icon that change the color on Focus and keep the icon color on focus when the edittext is not empty?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

**WHAT I'M LOOKING FOR ?**

> I want to keep the icon drawable on focus when the editTextView is not empty

I have a custom *editTextView* that have a left Drawable icon, and i have managed to change the icon drawable when the editTextView is *onFocus*, the problem is when i try keep the onFocus Drawable when the editTextVw is not empty, nothing happens, it's like only the **setOnFocusChangeListener** that works correctly.

> Here's the Images from the test EditTextView App :

the first image is when the editTextView is not onFocus

[image: the first image is when the editTextVw is not onFocus]

the second image is when the editTextVw is onFocus

[image: the second image is when the editTextVw is onFocus]

> and here's the code i used for changing the drawable when onFocus:

```
editTextVw2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVw2);
   editTextVw2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                Drawable focus_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_focus_18dp); //the focus_icon image
                focus_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(focus_icon);
                editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(focus_icon, null, null, null);
            } else {
                Drawable default_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_18dp); //the default image
                default_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(default_icon);
                editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(default_icon, null, null, null);
            }
        }
    });
```

-- I tried to add a method to check if the editTextVw is not Empty and apply this again

```
  Drawable focus_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_focus_18dp); //the focus_icon image
            focus_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(focus_icon);
            editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(focus_icon, null, null, null);
```

but it stays the same.

> What should be the quick solution for this ?

Comment: Just visualised your picture.

Answer (score 1):

you need to addTextChangedListener to your edittext too

```
editTextVw2.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            if (s.text.toString().isNotEmpty){
                //change color icon
            }

        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

It's so hard to understand what do you want. :)

Let me assume that you need to change the color of EditView left icon when this View is either on focus or not empty.

So, don't have any quick action provided by Google/Android team. The complete solution for you that I write below:

- (1) First, check your EditView status when you create a new one.
- (2) Add a listener for checking view focus or not.
- (3) If you allow this EditView's content had changed programmatically. Prepare for the onTextChanged listener.

Update: Following your source code, I think that should be.

```
editTextVw2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        boolean shouldDefault = !hasFocus;
        if (shouldDefault) {
            shouldDefault = TextUltis.isEmpty(
                    editTextVw2.getText().toString());
        }

        Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(
                shouldDefault ? R.drawable.user_18dp : R.drawable.user_focus_18dp);
        editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                default_icon, null, null, null);
    }
});
```

Comment: let me make it more simple :) ,   i want to change the icon when the editText is onFocus and when the EditText is not empty, otherwise the icon return to the default one when the editText is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you should change your code in `if` condition and `else` condition like this:

```
editTextVw2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextVw2);
   editTextVw2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                   Drawable default_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_18dp); //the default image
                default_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(default_icon);
                editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(default_icon, null, null, null);
            } else {

             Drawable focus_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_focus_18dp); //the focus_icon image
                focus_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(focus_icon);
                editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(focus_icon, null, null, null);
            }
        }
    });
```

I hope that help,
otherwise please describe more

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried this but didn't accomplish what i need, so after some erros i finnaly get what i need, i'll post my solution above. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

> thanks for your help, i finnaly get something like i need ,using this

```
editTextVw2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                // if the edit text is on focus change the icon 
                Drawable focus_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_focus_18dp); //the focus_icon image
                focus_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(focus_icon);
                editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(focus_icon, null, null, null);

                // if the edit text is not on focus
            } else {
                // and the edit text is not empty, change the ion
                if (editTextVw2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    Drawable focus_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_focus_18dp); //the focus_icon image
                    focus_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(focus_icon);
                    editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(focus_icon, null, null, null);
                    // otherwise if it's empty, return the the icon the the default one
                } else if (editTextVw2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                    Drawable default_icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_18dp); //the default image
                    default_icon = DrawableCompat.wrap(default_icon);
                    editTextVw2.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(default_icon, null, null, null);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

> If ther is a better way to do it pleas don't hesitat telling me